# How to create an Extension Method that accepts a class and an interface as a parameters

Tags: c#

For example I am trying to achieve this:

```
class A
{
}

class B
{
}

interface C 
{
  void SomeMethod();
}

A.ExtentionMethod(B,C);
```

Notice that I am passing the Type A and C to ExtentionMethod (Not an instance)

Comment: Pleas reformat your question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option would be to use generics instead of passing parameters

```
public static class Extensions
{
   public static void ExtensionMethod<T1, T2>(this A a)
   { 
       // ANywhere you would use the parameters use T1 and T2 instead.
   }
}

A a;
a.ExtensionMethod<B, C>();
```

IMO, this is more readable than when using `typeof()`.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
 public static class Util
    {
        public static void ExtensionMethod<t1, t2>(this A aobj)
   { 
   }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static class Extensions
{
   public static void ExtensionMethod(this A a, Type c1, Type c2)
   { 
   }
}

A a;
a.ExtensionMethod(typeof(B), typeof(C));
```

However, I don't see how this is very useful. Please be a bit more specific on what you want.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the interface like this

```
public static class Extension
{
    public static void Method1(this IMyInterface myInterface, int i)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Extension.Method1");
    }

    public static void Method1(this IMyInterface myInterface, string s)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Extension.Method1");
    }
}
```